# savedInstanceState in Fragment doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments

something wrong with my savedInstanceState into my Fragment.

The Save Instance doesn't work. When I switch back to "HomeMenu", all fields disappear.

On my Activity:

```
 private void selectItemFromDrawer(int position) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    Fragment fragment = null;
    String tagFrag = "default";
    switch (mNavItems.get(position).mTitle) {

        case R.string.menu_home:
            fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("menu_home");

            if(fragment == null) {
                fragment = new HomeMenuFragment();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(customActivity.this, "already Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            tagFrag = "menu_home";
            break;
        case R.string.menu_pref:
            fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("menu_pref");
            if(fragment == null)
                fragment = new PreferencesFragment();

            tagFrag = "menu_pref";
            break;
    }
    if(fragment != null) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment, tagFrag)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Thats works.. The Fragment change properly..

The TOAST works only if the Fragment is ACTIVE.. but not if I switch back to him.

example:

1. Home => Home => "toast Appear"
2. Home => Pref => Home => "No Toast".

Into my HomeMenuFragment I use this code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        strUser = savedInstanceState.getString("strUser", "");
        strName = savedInstanceState.getString("strName", "");
        strDesc = savedInstanceState.getString("strDesc", "");

        if(((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.user))!=null)
            ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.user)).setText(strUser);

        if(((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.name))!=null)
            ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(strName);
        if(((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.desc))!=null)
            ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.desc)).setText(strDesc);

    }
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("strUser", ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.user)).getText().toString());
    outState.putString("strName", ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString());
    outState.putString("strDesc", ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.desc)).getText().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll try to explain that, is not pretty easy.

In this case, your fragment is not destroyed, only the view inside it does.
So every view you used must implement state save/restore.

I left you a better explanation that mine, hope this helps you!
https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en

**Update**

Try to create fragment using newIstance, this is a best practice to avoid the loss of the parameters.
For example:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(String user, String name, String desc) {
    MyFragment mFragment = new MyFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("user", user);
    args.putString("name", name);
    args.putString("desc", desc);
    mFragment.setArguments(args);

    return mFragment;
}
```

And in the fragment `onCreate()` you can access the data by using:

```
String strUser = getArguments().getString("user", "");
```

If the fragment is recreated by Android, the Bundle will be available.
Remember, setArguments can only be called before the Fragment is attached to the Activity.

Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) documentation, there is no `putString()` nor `getString()` methods, you need to use `putStringArrayList (String key, ArrayList<String> value)`. I also suggest you avoid so many calls on getActivity().findViewById(), it is well known that it causes a lot of overhead.  Also, why are you obtaining view values from the activity inside a fragment? Looks like duplicated code. Anyway, try this:

```
 TextView tvUser, tvName, tvDesc;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Store TextView references calling findViewById only once
    tvUser =  ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.user));
    tvName  = ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.user));
    tvDesc = ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.user));
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        al = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("args");
        tvUser.setText(al.get(0));
        tvName.setText(al.get(1));
        tvDesc.setText(al.get(2));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    al.add(0, tvUser.getText());
    al.add(1, tvName.getText());
    al.add(2, tvDesc.getText());
    outState.putStringArrayList("args", al);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It didn't work.
It help a little. I have persistent only when I return tu `home to home` ... If I switch to `preference` and comeback to `home` I loose my field. I add `else Toast ` into `onActivityCreated` and the toast appear when I do `home => pref => home` well.. I don't have saveInstanceState.

Answer (score -1):

It might be that you call the `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)` before you put the strings which you hope to save. To solve this, you simply need to call `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)` **AFTER** putting the values you hope to save. Here are the changes you need to make:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {    
    outState.putString("strUser", ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.user)).getText().toString());
    outState.putString("strName", ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString());
    outState.putString("strDesc", ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.desc)).getText().toString());
    //moved it here
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

I hope this solves your problem. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Does this mean that `savedInstanceState` is still null or what exactly is happening?